# unfortunately program has stopped

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-search

I am making a simple list view with search in android studio. I have created this class:
Success.java

```
public class Success extends Activity {
    protected String[] plates = {"AA 367 AM", "AA 367 AL","AA 367 AK"};
    protected ListAdapter adapter;
    private ListView myListView;
    EditText inputSearch;
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.success);

        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.searchText);
        myListView = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.list);
        myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.plates, R.id.plate_name, plates);
        myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
                String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Success.this,Info.class);
                intent.putExtra("Plate",item);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                Success.this.myAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            }
        });
    }
  }
```

and success.xml

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchButton"
        android:text="Search"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The search works but on item click it shows **unfortunately program2 has stopped**
Info.java

```
public class Info extends Activity {
    ImageView imageView2;
    ImageView imageView3;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);
        imageView2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

        TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intent3);


        String plate = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Plate");
        tv3.setText(""+getIntent().getExtras().getString("Plate"));

        imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.car1);
        imageView3.setImageResource(R.drawable.status1);

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
07-18 10:34:08.343      164-165/? E/RSA﹕ clarence - socket_local_client error! 111
07-18 10:34:08.349      164-164/? D/ADB_SERVICES﹕ adb fdevent_process list (15) (22)
07-18 10:34:08.349      164-164/? D/ADB_SERVICES﹕ adb socket read list (22)
07-18 10:34:08.349      164-164/? D/ADB_SERVICES﹕ read_data=11265
07-18 10:34:08.349      164-164/? D/ADB_SERVICES﹕ max_read_time=0.000107 max_send_time=0.000073
07-18 10:34:08.499  10816-10816/com.Program2 I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x51ae9cf0) fps:1.99, dur:1003.59, max:505.02, min:498.57
07-18 10:34:08.500      133-468/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [com.Program2/com.Program2.Main](this:0x41d27a40,api:2) [queue] fps:1.99, dur:1003.56, max:504.90, min:498.66
07-18 10:34:08.505      133-173/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [com.Program2/com.Program2.Main](this:0x41d27a40,api:2) [release] fps:1.99, dur:1003.57, max:501.79, min:501.78
07-18 10:34:08.506      133-173/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ [SurfaceFlinger] fps:3.985810,dur:1003.56,max:351.11,min:150.66
07-18 10:34:08.791      510-574/? D/StateMachine﹕ handleMessage: E msg.what=131155
07-18 10:34:08.791      510-574/? D/StateMachine﹕ processMsg: ConnectedState
07-18 10:34:08.792      510-574/? D/WifiStateMachine﹕ ConnectedState{ what=131155 when=-4ms arg1=2 target=Handler (com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler) {416e4d80} }
07-18 10:34:08.792      510-574/? D/StateMachine﹕ processMsg: L2ConnectedState
07-18 10:34:08.793      510-574/? D/WifiStateMachine﹕ L2ConnectedState{ what=131155 when=-5ms arg1=2 target=Handler (com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler) {416e4d80} }
07-18 10:34:08.793      510-574/? D/WifiNative-wlan0﹕ doString: SIGNAL_POLL
07-18 10:34:08.793      510-574/? D/WifiCommon﹕ [wlan0] SET "SIGNAL_POLL"
07-18 10:34:08.794      719-719/? D/wpa_supplicant﹕ RX ctrl_iface - hexdump(len=11): 53 49 47 4e 41 4c 5f 50 4f 4c 4c
07-18 10:34:08.794      719-719/? D/wpa_supplicant﹕ wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
07-18 10:34:08.816      719-719/? D/wpa_supplicant﹕ nl80211: survey data missing!
07-18 10:34:08.817      510-574/? I/WifiStateMachine﹕ fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative, newRssi:-58, newLinkSpeed:54
07-18 10:34:08.817      510-574/? D/StateMachine﹕ handleMessage: X
07-18 10:34:09.344      164-165/? E/RSA﹕ clarence - socket_local_client error! 111
07-18 10:34:09.345      670-670/? I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x52d9c570) fps:1.33, dur:1506.00, max:1003.20, min:502.79
07-18 10:34:09.346      133-357/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [StatusBar](this:0x41d0b948,api:1) [queue] fps:1.33, dur:1506.66, max:1003.91, min:502.75
07-18 10:34:09.352      164-164/? D/ADB_SERVICES﹕ adb local_socket_ready list (22)
07-18 10:34:09.358      133-173/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [StatusBar](this:0x41d0b948,api:1) [release] fps:1.33, dur:1505.35, max:1003.48, min:501.87
07-18 10:34:09.861      133-173/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ [SurfaceFlinger] fps:2.952940,dur:1354.58,max:501.69,min:133.93
07-18 10:34:09.987  10816-10816/com.Program2 I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x51ae9cf0) fps:2.02, dur:1487.80, max:501.54, min:485.06
07-18 10:34:09.988      133-133/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [com.Program2/com.Program2.Main](this:0x41d27a40,api:2) [queue] fps:2.02, dur:1487.84, max:501.43, min:485.05
07-18 10:34:09.994      133-173/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [com.Program2/com.Program2.Main](this:0x41d27a40,api:2) [release] fps:2.02, dur:1488.59, max:501.77, min:485.05
07-18 10:34:10.320      510-530/? V/Provider/Settings﹕ from settings cache , name = read_external_storage_enforced_default , value = null
07-18 10:34:10.322    134-10867/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=2: exiting
07-18 10:34:10.322    134-10867/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=2: bye!
07-18 10:34:10.323    134-10875/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: exiting
07-18 10:34:10.323    134-10875/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: bye!
07-18 10:34:10.325    134-10876/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=4: exiting
07-18 10:34:10.325    134-10876/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=4: bye!
07-18 10:34:10.326      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ pre gc
07-18 10:34:10.326      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Zygote::ForkAndSpecialize +
07-18 10:34:10.337      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Zygote::ForkAndSpecialize : 10880
07-18 10:34:10.338      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create interp thread : stack size=32KB
07-18 10:34:10.339  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Zygote::ForkAndSpecialize : 0
07-18 10:34:10.340      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create new thread
07-18 10:34:10.343      162-162/? I/sdcard﹕ [0] SETATTR fh=0 valid=1 @ 40a36070 (0)
07-18 10:34:10.343      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ new thread created
07-18 10:34:10.343      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ update thread list
07-18 10:34:10.344      164-165/? E/RSA﹕ clarence - socket_local_client error! 111
07-18 10:34:10.349      670-670/? I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x52d9c570) fps:1.99, dur:1004.20, max:503.14, min:501.06
07-18 10:34:10.350      133-468/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [StatusBar](this:0x41d0b948,api:1) [queue] fps:1.99, dur:1004.12, max:503.78, min:500.34
07-18 10:34:10.352  10880-10880/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/0, 0, 0)
07-18 10:34:10.353      162-169/? I/sdcard﹕ [1] SETATTR fh=0 valid=6 @ 40a36070 (0)
07-18 10:34:10.354      162-162/? I/sdcard﹕ [0] SETATTR fh=0 valid=1 @ 40a36148 (obb)
07-18 10:34:10.355  10880-10880/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/obb, 0, 0)
07-18 10:34:10.356      162-162/? I/sdcard﹕ [0] SETATTR fh=0 valid=6 @ 40a36148 (obb)
07-18 10:34:10.357      162-162/? I/sdcard﹕ [0] SETATTR fh=0 valid=1 @ 40a36190 (Android)
07-18 10:34:10.358  10880-10880/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android, 0, 0)
07-18 10:34:10.359      162-169/? I/sdcard﹕ [1] SETATTR fh=0 valid=6 @ 40a36190 (Android)
07-18 10:34:10.360      162-169/? I/sdcard﹕ [1] SETATTR fh=0 valid=1 @ 40a361d8 (obb)
07-18 10:34:10.360  10880-10880/? E/cutils﹕ to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb, 0, 0)
07-18 10:34:10.362      133-173/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [StatusBar](this:0x41d0b948,api:1) [release] fps:1.99, dur:1003.61, max:501.82, min:501.79
07-18 10:34:10.363      162-162/? I/sdcard﹕ [0] SETATTR fh=0 valid=6 @ 40a361d8 (obb)
07-18 10:34:10.365    134-10881/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=2: interp stack at 0x4f3c6000
07-18 10:34:10.366  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ zygote get new systemTid : 10880
07-18 10:34:10.367  10880-10882/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=2: interp stack at 0x4f4c6000
07-18 10:34:10.368    134-10881/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=2: created from interp
07-18 10:34:10.368      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ start new thread
07-18 10:34:10.368      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create interp thread : stack size=32KB
07-18 10:34:10.368      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create new thread
07-18 10:34:10.368      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ new thread created
07-18 10:34:10.368      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ update thread list
07-18 10:34:10.369    134-10881/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=2: notify debugger
07-18 10:34:10.369    134-10881/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=2 (ReferenceQueueDaemon): calling run()
07-18 10:34:10.370  10880-10884/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: interp stack at 0x4f5ce000
07-18 10:34:10.371  10880-10884/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Elevating priority from 0 to -8
07-18 10:34:10.371  10880-10885/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=4: interp stack at 0x4f6d6000
07-18 10:34:10.371  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ zygote get thread init done
07-18 10:34:10.372  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create interp thread : stack size=32KB
07-18 10:34:10.372  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create new thread
07-18 10:34:10.372  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ new thread created
07-18 10:34:10.373    134-10883/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: interp stack at 0x4f4ce000
07-18 10:34:10.373    134-10883/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: created from interp
07-18 10:34:10.373  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ update thread list
07-18 10:34:10.373  10880-10886/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=5: interp stack at 0x51af4000
07-18 10:34:10.373      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ start new thread
07-18 10:34:10.374      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create interp thread : stack size=32KB
07-18 10:34:10.374      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create new thread
07-18 10:34:10.374      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ new thread created
07-18 10:34:10.374      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ update thread list
07-18 10:34:10.375    134-10883/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: notify debugger
07-18 10:34:10.375    134-10883/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3 (FinalizerDaemon): calling run()
07-18 10:34:10.375  10880-10886/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=5: created from interp
07-18 10:34:10.375  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ start new thread
07-18 10:34:10.376  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create interp thread : stack size=32KB
07-18 10:34:10.376  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create new thread
07-18 10:34:10.376  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ new thread created
07-18 10:34:10.376  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ update thread list
07-18 10:34:10.376  10880-10886/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=5: notify debugger
07-18 10:34:10.376  10880-10886/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=5 (ReferenceQueueDaemon): calling run()
07-18 10:34:10.377  10880-10888/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=6: interp stack at 0x51bfc000
07-18 10:34:10.377  10880-10888/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=6: created from interp
07-18 10:34:10.377  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ start new thread
07-18 10:34:10.378  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create interp thread : stack size=32KB
07-18 10:34:10.379  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create new thread
07-18 10:34:10.379  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ new thread created
07-18 10:34:10.379  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ update thread list
07-18 10:34:10.379  10880-10888/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=6: notify debugger
07-18 10:34:10.379  10880-10888/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=6 (FinalizerDaemon): calling run()
07-18 10:34:10.380  10880-10889/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=7: interp stack at 0x51d04000
07-18 10:34:10.380  10880-10889/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=7: created from interp
07-18 10:34:10.380  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ start new thread
07-18 10:34:10.381    134-10887/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=4: interp stack at 0x4f5d6000
07-18 10:34:10.381    134-10887/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=4: created from interp
07-18 10:34:10.382      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ start new thread
07-18 10:34:10.392    134-10887/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=4: notify debugger
07-18 10:34:10.392    134-10887/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=4 (FinalizerWatchdogDaemon): calling run()
07-18 10:34:10.393      510-530/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.feelingtouch.dipan.slggameglobal for service com.feelingtouch.dipan.slggameglobal/com.amazonaws.androidtest.MessageReceivingService: pid=10880 uid=10099 gids={50099, 3003, 1028, 1015}
07-18 10:34:10.399  10880-10889/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=7: notify debugger
07-18 10:34:10.399  10880-10889/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=7 (FinalizerWatchdogDaemon): calling run()
07-18 10:34:10.399  10843-10856/? I/ATCIJ﹕ Couldn't find 'atci-serv-fw' socket; retrying after timeout
07-18 10:34:10.399  10880-10890/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=8: interp stack at 0x5210a000
07-18 10:34:10.413  10880-10891/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=9: interp stack at 0x52212000
07-18 10:34:10.415     510-1141/? V/ActivityManager﹕ Binding process pid 10880 to record ProcessRecord{417db9c8 10880:com.feelingtouch.dipan.slggameglobal/u0a10099}
07-18 10:34:10.415     510-1141/? V/ActivityManager﹕ New death recipient com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AppDeathRecipient@414e95b8 for thread android.os.BinderProxy@41aa2d30
07-18 10:34:10.416     510-1141/? V/ActivityManager﹕ New app record ProcessRecord{417db9c8 10880:com.feelingtouch.dipan.slggameglobal/u0a10099} thread=android.os.BinderProxy@41aa2d30 pid=10880
07-18 10:34:10.419      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 42K (1048), 8% free 2558K/2752K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 37ms
07-18 10:34:10.447  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ open_cached_dex_file : /data/app/com.feelingtouch.dipan.slggameglobal-1.apk /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.feelingtouch.dipan.slggameglobal-1.apk@classes.dex
07-18 10:34:10.454  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create interp thread : stack size=32KB
07-18 10:34:10.454  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create new thread
07-18 10:34:10.454  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ new thread created
07-18 10:34:10.455  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ update thread list
07-18 10:34:10.455      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K (2), 8% free 2558K/2752K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 35ms
07-18 10:34:10.455  10880-10892/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=10: interp stack at 0x52855000
07-18 10:34:10.456  10880-10892/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=10: created from interp
07-18 10:34:10.456  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ start new thread
07-18 10:34:10.457  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create interp thread : stack size=32KB
07-18 10:34:10.458  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create new thread
07-18 10:34:10.459  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ new thread created
07-18 10:34:10.459  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ update thread list
07-18 10:34:10.459  10880-10892/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=10: notify debugger
07-18 10:34:10.459  10880-10892/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=10 (SharedPreferencesImpl-load): calling run()
07-18 10:34:10.465  10880-10893/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: interp stack at 0x5295d000
07-18 10:34:10.465  10880-10893/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: created from interp
07-18 10:34:10.465  10880-10880/? D/dalvikvm﹕ start new thread
07-18 10:34:10.469  10880-10892/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=10: exiting
07-18 10:34:10.469  10880-10892/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=10: bye!
07-18 10:34:10.470  10880-10893/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: notify debugger
07-18 10:34:10.470  10880-10893/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11 (SharedPreferencesImpl-load): calling run()
07-18 10:34:10.470  10880-10893/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: exiting
07-18 10:34:10.470  10880-10893/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: bye!
07-18 10:34:10.491      134-134/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K (5), 8% free 2558K/2752K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 35ms
07-18 10:34:10.515      510-736/? V/ActivityManager﹕ getTasks: max=1, flags=0, receiver=null
07-18 10:34:10.515      510-736/? V/ActivityManager﹕ com.Program2/.Main: task=TaskRecord{41e8e048 #18 A com.Program2 U 0}
07-18 10:34:10.516      510-736/? V/ActivityManager﹕ We have pending thumbnails: null
07-18 10:34:10.865      133-173/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ [SurfaceFlinger] fps:3.985524,dur:1003.63,max:368.79,min:132.94
07-18 10:34:10.991  10816-10816/com.Program2 I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x51ae9cf0) fps:1.99, dur:1003.49, max:503.53, min:499.96
07-18 10:34:10.991     133-1738/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [com.Program2/com.Program2.Main](this:0x41d27a40,api:2) [queue] fps:1.99, dur:1003.50, max:503.46, min:500.04
07-18 10:34:10.997      133-173/? I/BufferQueue﹕ [com.Program2/com.Program2.Main](this:0x41d27a40,api:2) [release] fps:1.99, dur:1003.55, max:502.00, min:501.55
```

Comment: Show the logcat output for the error.

Comment: is Info declared in the Manifest?

Comment: Yes it is declared @blackbelt

Comment: @Ved Prakash the error is displayed on tablet when test the program. The code is executed without any error.

Comment: It wouldn't crash and say "unfortunately has stopped" if you didn't get an exception, meaning the code is NOT executed without any error. Post the logcat.

Comment: clear the storage data and cache for the app and try, else you need to post your logcat with error

Comment: @Zhuinden edited with logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is when listItemClicked, you cast the view to TextView and this is wrong. You should use `String item = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewID)).getText().toString()`

Comment: yourTextViewID which textviewId should be?

Comment: yes but at success.xml I have only ListView and EditText (for search) which is the textview?

Comment: then what is the "R.id.plate_name"? I think you should place this id.